# Use COL name to Get ROW names based on whether a value exists in a Column with the specified Name

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Would deeply appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

**Overview**

In a google sheet I have the following grid:

|  | School A | School B | School C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | x |  | x |
| John |  |  |  |
| Martin | x | x |  |
| Jack |  |  | x |

The Rows are Names of people who cater to certain schools. The value 'x' in the cell simply signifies the relation. So **Tim** caters to **School A & School C** and similarly **Jack** only caters to **School C**.

**Note:** The cells are either empty or contain that 'x'. Thought that might help. We don't really need to look for 'x' just a non-empty cell.

**Question**

I have another table like follows, where I have a School column listing all the schools in rows. 
 I would like to create a formula to use the table above and return a concatenated string listing all the people catering to that school.

| School | *People* |
| --- | --- |
| School A | *Tim, Martin* |
| School B | *Martin* |
| School C | *Tim, Jack* |

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B2:D="",,B1:D1&"♠♦"&A2:A&",♦"&A2:A)), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 is not nUll group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), "♠")), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks so amazing! (trying it right now) way beyond my sheet skills. I did have a question though, I don't see you referencing column F. Would this create a new Table? I have an existing Table with School rows (and other columns in front of  it). In the example above I wanted to add the formula in G2, G3, G4 using the values in F2, F3, F4

Comment: BTW, you are amazing!!!

Comment: This is working great, I can definitely just use this and do lookup from this table. However I am getting leading ',' in the string like **", Craig, Crowder, Hann, Maciel"**

Comment: @Tahir if you want to do lookup use: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 {B1:D1&"♦"; IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&",")},,9^9)), "♦")), ",$", ), 2, 0)))`

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 {B1:D1&"♦"; IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&",")},,9^9)), "♦")), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: This one works Perfectly! Thank you so much! I am so grateful!